# Subtract even rows from odd rows using awk, etc

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am working with some data in the bash shell and need to manipulate it using sed/awk, etc and need to subtract even rows from the odd rows.

For instance:

```
51202598
51204294
51370060
51371733
51535314
51536526
```

would become:

```
1696
1673
1212
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't subtracting the even rows from the odd rows lead to `-1696, -1673, -1212`?  Or do you want the absolute value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk 'NR%2{p=$1;next}{print ($1-p)}' file
1696
1673
1212
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much for the quick answer. Waiting to "accept answer in 10 minutes" :)

Comment: +1. A little variation: `awk '{p=$1; getline; print $1-p}' file`

Answer (score 3):

Just for the fun of not using awk:

```
cat calc.data | paste - - | xargs -I{} echo {} "- _1 * p" | dc
```

or even shorter:

```
xargs -a calc.data -l2 printf "%s %s - _1 * p" | dc
```

with `sed` and `bc` (via comment by glenn):

```
sed -n 'h;n;G;s,\n,-,;p' calc.data|bc
```

or with `dc` alone (but in reverse order):

```
dc -f calc.data -e '[-_1*pswz1<r]srz1<r'
```

Comment: heh, nice. I counter with `tac calc.data | paste -d'-' - - | bc | tac`

Comment: Hehe, thank you glenn. I bet even the `printf` can be removed somehow. :D

Comment: I can golf it down to: `sed -n 'h;n;G;s,\n,-,;p' calc.data|bc`

Comment: This one is reverse `dc -f calc.data -e '[-_1*pswz1<r]srz1<r'` but pure `dc`